# Telerik namespace not found in deployed MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have just deployed a new MVC3 application, and after some efforts on my hosting provider's side, MVC3 seems to be running OK, but now I get the following compilation error before anything on the site loads:

*CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Telerik' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

This occurs in web.config on the following line:

```
<add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI" />
```

I know the DLL is present in the bin folder on the host, so I'm a bit lost as to what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Razor this line:

```
<add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI" />
```

must occur in `~/Views/web.config` and not in `~/web.config`. Could this be your case?

Like this:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: I had it in both, and even just tried removing it from the root web.config, with no difference.

Comment: I accepted this as the most valid and useful answer although it did not solve my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: I just searched telerik mvc namespace and came here. This answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/issue-with-telerik-mvc3-razor-content-appearing-at-the-top.aspx

Read the reply by Mike Kidder. Sorry for linking another forum, I know that's annoying but I'd rather give credit where due.

> Two big takeaways when converting to Razor syntax:
>
> 1)  Use  @(   ....   )  when outputting html,  not  @{   ....  ;}
>       - wrap the code for Telerik controls in parentheses, not brackets
>       - using brackets, you're essentially telling Razor to execute a method. You won't get any output
>
> 2)  Remove the ".Render()" method for any Telerik controls.  Not used in Razor.

Comment: Thanks @all2neat, but Mike Kidder's reply, and most of that topic, have nothing to do with my question.  I have no problem with .Render() at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set Copy Local to true for the assemblies you have referenced. In your case expand References, select the assembly, press F4 to open the properties and set Copy Local to true. The assembly most probably is installed in the GAC so when you add a reference to it by default Copy Local is false.

Answer (score 0):

it might be in the bin folder but, since you didn't mention this, did you actually add reference to the file in the project? after adding the reference to the dll, it should build correctly

Comment: The app won't build without a proper reference, which I have had from the beginning anyway.